# Why are values not getting parsed from span file on website?

Tags: java, arraylist, jsoup

I am trying to retrieve information from IMDB, specifically titles, dates, and ratings of films.  Jsoup is able to parse the titles and dates, but not the ratings.

The element is written like this:

```
<span class="ipl-rating-star_rating">7.3</span>
```

and I have this written in my code as such:

```
Elements rating = doc.select("span.ipl-rating-star_rating");
```

The dates and ratings both come from span class, and so in my program the code for those look similar, but only dates work:

```
for(Element f: year) {//add to array list "date"
            date.add(f.getElementsByTag("span").first().text());
}


for(Element g: rating) {//add to array list "ratings"
            ratings.add(g.getElementsByTag("span").first().text());
}
```

When I print date.size(), I get 82, but ratings.size() displays 0.

Here is the URL of the website:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.imdb.com/list/ls005750764/").get();
```

Comment: Elements rating = doc.select("span.ipl-rating-star_rating"); You have used ipl rating but in actual span you have mentioned 'ill' rating

Comment: I'm sorry it is ipl, it was a typo from autocorrect, I'll edit the post, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Can you add the url you are trying to parse?

Comment: yes I can do that, ill put it in right now for everyone

Comment: You have a typo - there are **double** underscores in the class' name - `star__rating`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I was not aware that it was a double underscore, its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Worth checking the docs: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax as there are some good examples...

I think you want:

```java
doc.select("span[class=ipl-rating-star_rating]");
```